# Best way to run common function from different classes

Tags: scala, types, functional-programming

I have this classes

```
public abstract class Foo {
    def execute: Unit = ???
}

public abstract class Bar {
    def execute: Unit = ???
}

public class FooFoo extends Foo {
    def execute: Unit = ???
}

public class BarBar extends Bar {
    def execute: Unit = ???
}
```

In some where I have this method:

```
def executeSomething(body: => AnyRef) : = Try(body) match ...
```

And the calls look like this

```
x match {
  case _: Foo => executeSomething(x.execute)
  case _: Bar => executeSomething(x.execute)
}
```

Is there are some way then I can do that like this (without new classes )

```
val u = executeSomething(x)
```

?

**upd**

sorry, guys. This m.b. real code will be more clear

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorLogging, ActorRef, Props}
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeTokenRequest
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException
import com.google.api.services.analytics.Analytics
import com.google.api.services.analyticsreporting.v4.AnalyticsReporting
import com.my.lab.messages.{GRequest, GResponse}
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

class GQueueTask(req: GRequest, ref: ActorRef) extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  def receive: Receive = {
    case _ =>
  }

  def execute(body: => AnyRef): Unit = {
    Try(body) match {
      case Success(r) => ref ! GResponse(req, response = Option(r))
      case Failure(f: GoogleJsonResponseException) =>
            f.printStackTrace()
            ref ! GResponse(req, error = Option(f))
      case _ => ref ! GResponse(req, Option("unknown error"))
    }
  }

  req match {
    case GRequest(request, _) => request match {
      case x: AnalyticsReporting#Reports#BatchGet => execute(x.execute()) // AbstractGoogleClientRequest
      case x: Analytics#Data#Ga#Get => execute(x.execute()) // AbstractGoogleClientRequest
      case x: Analytics#Management#Accounts#List => execute(x.execute()) // AbstractGoogleClientRequest
      case x: Analytics#Management#Webproperties#List => execute(x.execute()) // AbstractGoogleClientRequest
      case x: Analytics#Management#Profiles#List => execute(x.execute()) // AbstractGoogleClientRequest
      case x: AuthorizationCodeTokenRequest => execute(x.execute()) // TokenRequest
      case _ => ref ! GResponse(req)
    }
  }

  context stop self
}
```

I tried to simplify "request match" block

Comment: Why not extend Function and just call `val u = x()`? With `apply` instead of `execute`.

Comment: I have some legacy code looks like this. I can modify only executeSomething and code below :(

Comment: Can't you just use overloaded executeSomething? `def executeSomething(x:Foo) = x.execute;
def executeSomething(x:Bar) = x.execute`?

Comment: What is the `x`? Result of `Try(Body)`? Could you please reread your question and make it a bit more clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although you can achieve it by using structural typing (duck typing), it has a lot of overhead since scala use introspection at runtime. I think The best way to achieve it is by using type classes. It's in use in Scala all over the place :) Scala's Ordering is one example.

A type class defines functionality associated with "unrelated" types.
What you need to do is define the type class in the form of a trait:

```
trait Executable[T] {
    def execute(t: T): Unit
}
```

Than you need to make your types a member of that type class, for example:

```
implicit object FooFooExecutable extends Executable[FooFoo] {
  override def execute(t: FooFoo): Unit = t.execute()
}
```

And the last thing is to define the method that takes your type class as an argument.

```
def exec[T: Executable](t: T): Unit = {
  implicitly[ExecTypeClass[T]].execute(t)
}
```

You can read more about type classes [here](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/06/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-12-type-classes.html), [here](http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/demystifying-implicits-and-typeclasses-in-scala) and [here](http://www.lihaoyi.com/post/ImplicitDesignPatternsinScala.html)

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a pretty good use-case for `duck-typing`.

`Duck Typing` is more formally referred as `Structural Types`.

A `Duck Type` can be thought of as just a `specification` of desired set of properties. `Compile time reflection` is used to ensure that the `type` of provided parameter is compatible with the `specification` of your `duck-type`. So it provides you compile-time type-safety.

And then it uses `run time reflection` to actually call the respective methods on provided instance.

So,

Lets say you have following abstractions,

```
abstract class Foo {
  def execute(): Unit
}

abstract class Bar {
  def execute(): Unit
}

class FooFoo extends Foo {
  override def execute(): Unit = {
    println("FooFoo")
  }
}

class BarBar extends Bar {
  override def execute(): Unit = {
    println("BarBar")
  }
}
```

Note :: I have added `()` to all your `Unit` methods. This is a convention in Scala that all methods with side-effects should have `()`. And a `Unit` method can not do anything other than side effects.

Now... you just need to define a `duck-type` for the shared behaviour,

```
type HasExecuteMethod = {
  def execute(): Unit
}
```

Now... lets define a function which uses this duck-type,

```
def doExecute(hasExecuteMethod: HasExecuteMethod): Unit = {
  hasExecuteMethod.execute()
}
```

And... here you have it. This `doExecute` method will accept instance of any class which has a `def execute(): Unit` member.

Comment: What language do you use? Scala don't have `public class`, it requires `override` modifier in `FooFoo`, `BarBar`, and, most important, trick with `type` does not work.

Comment: I had actually thought that since OP ha asked such a good question, the code provided will not have such obvious mistakes like `public`. And you actually do not "need" to specify `override`. You do that as a good practice to guard against mistakes.

Comment: @dveim It will all work now. I did forget to type that `=`. It should have been `type HasExecuteMethod = {`. And as for the public thing... I copy pasted from OP's question and I did not notice these obvious problems in hurry.

Comment: @dveim Now that I have fixed it. Can you please remove that `trick with type does not work` part, so that people coming to this question can be made aware of `duck-typing`.

Comment: Thanks for fixing those syntactic issues. By `trick with type does not work` I meant combination of 1) syntax errors (so REPL wasn't working) 2) I didn't know that one can describe structural types in that way :) Just for the sake of clarity, could you please add that your answer uses reflection?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it worked:

```
object Dummy {
  abstract class Foo {
    def execute: Unit
  }

  abstract class Bar {
    def execute: Unit
  }

  class FooFoo extends Foo {
    def execute: Unit = { println("Foo") }
  }

  class BarBar extends Bar {
    def execute: Unit = { println("Bar") }
  }

  def run(x: AnyRef): Unit = {

    x match {
      case f: Foo => f.execute
      case b: Bar => b.execute
      case _ =>
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val any = new BarBar()
    run(any)
  }
}
```

It printed

```
Bar
```